# Converting a array into a max heap

Tags: c

I wrote some code to build a max heap in C but I'm getting a very unlikely output. The output goes well with certain inputs but is incorrect with other inputs. How can a fix this?

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i)
{
    int temp;
    int largest = i; // Initialize largest as root
    int l = 2 * i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1
    int r = 2 * i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2

    // If left child is larger than root
    if (l < n && arr[l] > arr[largest])
        largest = l;

    // If right child is larger than largest so far
    if (r < n && arr[r] > arr[largest])
        largest = r;

    // If largest is not root
    if (largest != i) {
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[largest];
            arr[largest]=temp;
        }

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

// Function to build a Max-Heap from the given array
void buildHeap(int arr[], int n)
{
    // Index of last non-leaf node
    int i;

    // Perform reverse level order traversal
    // from last non-leaf node and heapify
    // each node
    for ( i = n/2-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(arr, n, i);
    }
}

// A utility function to print the array
// representation of Heap
void printHeap(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,3,5,4,6,13,110,9,8,15,17};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("the array is");
    printHeap(arr,n);

    buildHeap(arr,n);
    printf("the heap is");
    printHeap(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

For an input of `11 67 45 89 34` the output comes out to be  `89 67 45 11 34`. If we replace 34 with some other number that is  smaller than 11, the output makes sense. When I work it on pen and paper I can easily make out that the input of 34 is not touched upon except during the first function call for heapify where i is 1 and left and right is 3 and 4 respectively. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code isn't broken? The only requirement is that the parent is greater than its children, which is the case: 67 is greater than both 11 and 34.

Comment: but when we display a heap as an array shouldn't it be displayed in descending order? with the left child being smaller then the right child,that is how a heap is  represented in most of the textbooks

Comment: That can happen but it's not required by a heap. The algorithm for constructing a heap does not account for that.